# Is there any limit for sign in to Twitter App?

Tags: php, twitter, authentication, oauth

I have a simple Twitter app based on OAuth in PHP and sometimes happen, that if I am working with the app and testing login into the app & stuffs around, so sometimes I can login into the app.

Is there any limit of how many times I can login into build app let's say per day/hour or it's a bug on Twitter hand/in library?

Answer (score 0):

According to the API docs, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api#oauth, requests to authentication endpoints are not rate limited. If you're seeing errors while logging in, it's likely a reason other than rate limiting.